# Ruby (Rack) application could not be started - Passenger (3.0.9) error for rails 3.1.0 app on ubuntu and nginx (1.0.6) after deploying

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx, passenger, bcrypt

Here is the error saying bcrypt was not loaded. The rails app is not using the Devise for authentication and gem bcrypt is not in Gemfile. Sometime, the webserver throws out the error saying spawn server can not start. gem list shows that both bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1 and 3.0.0 were installed.

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
A source file that the application requires, is missing.

    *
      It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
    *
      A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:
    no such file to load -- bcrypt
Exception class:
    LoadError
Application root:
    /vol/www/emclab/current 
Backtrace:
    #   File    Line    Location
    0   /vol/www/emclab/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    240     in `require'
    1   /vol/www/emclab/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    240     in `block in require'
    2   /vol/www/emclab/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    225     in `load_dependency'
    3   /vol/www/emclab/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    240     in `require'
    4   /vol/www/emclab/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.0/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb     1   in `'
    5   /vol/www/emclab/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb  2160    in `block in '
    6   /vol/www/emclab/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb  2140    in `class_eval'
    7   /vol/www/emclab/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb  2140    in `'
    8   /vol/www/emclab/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb  31  in `'
    9   /vol/www/emclab/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/session_store.rb     77  in `'
    10  /vol/www/emclab/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/session_store.rb     51  in `'
```

cap deploy:check returns:

```
You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed
```

Any thoughts about the problem? thanks!

Comment: Having a similar problem. I suspect it has something to do with bcrypt and being on ubuntu 64 bit.